# Tensorflow for mac AVX

Tags: python, tensorflow, avx

I'm using TensorFlow but I'm getting the following warning

> The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but
> these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU
> computations

I installed it using pip.

How can I fix it?

Comment: @sophros - please don't use `code formatting` for highlighting, or names that aren't specifically variable or function names from code.  It looks ugly and apparently messes things up for screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you installed using pip it's a precompiled package that wasn't precompiled to the architecture you use, you need to build it from the source.

You can refer to he official tensorflow documentation on how to compile it from the source

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources